# cannot get the last zero from decimal value

Tags: php, decimal

I am getting a value, say

```
$val=12345.80;
```

I when I receive and echoing it , it is showing as

```
12345.8
```

But I want it as the original value i.e.

```
12345.80
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You want to read about how floating point values are handled in computers. If you want to have a specific formatting of such a value, then you need to format it. The computer cannot _guess_ how you want the value to be formatted. php offers functions to format the output of a numeric value.

Comment: probably you are looking for `number_format()`? http://php.net/manual/bg/function.number-format.php

Comment: Use sprintf() or number_format()

Answer (score 1):

You can format your number, like so:

```
$val=12345.80;
echo number_format($val, 2, '.', ''); // 12345.80
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use formatting on output to indicate that you are interested in 2 decimal places with the printed representation.

The value `12345.80` is perfectly represented by `12345.8` (Not to say, it is equal in a mathematical sense).

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your problem:

```
<?php
$var1 = 12345.80;
$var2 = sprintf('%0.2f', $var1);
echo $var2;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.